How to stop RichEditBox from attempting to interpret KeyboardAccelerators on Buttons?
I have some buttons that use KeyboardAccelerators
        <Button x:Name="butPrevPanel" AutomationProperties.Name="Previous Panel" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Previous Panel" RelativePanel.RightOf="butGo" RelativePanel.Below="menuBar"
                Click="Button_PreviousPanel_Click">
            <Button.Content>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE892;" />
            </Button.Content>
            <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
                <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control,Shift" Key="Tab"/>
            </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="butNextPanel" AutomationProperties.Name="Previous Panel" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Previous Panel" RelativePanel.RightOf="butPrevPanel" RelativePanel.Below="menuBar"
                Click="Button_NextPanel_Click">
            <Button.Content>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE893;" />
            </Button.Content>
            <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
                <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="Tab"/>
            </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
        </Button>

How do I stop my RichEditBoxes from intercepting these KeyboardAccelerators when focus is on the RichEditBox?

You can use the Invoked event:
<Page
    x:Class="KeyboardAcceleratorsDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:KeyboardAcceleratorsDemo"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Click="Button_Click">
                <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator
                        Key="F2"
                        Invoked="KeyboardAccelerator_Invoked"
                        Modifiers="None" />
                </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
            </Button>

        </StackPanel>
        <RichEditBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            GotFocus="RichEditBox_GotFocus"
            LostFocus="RichEditBox_LostFocus" />
    </Grid>

</Page>

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool IgnoreKeyboardAccelerators { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Button Clicked");
    }

    private void KeyboardAccelerator_Invoked(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyboardAccelerator sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Handled = IgnoreKeyboardAccelerators;
    }

    private void RichEditBox_GotFocus(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IgnoreKeyboardAccelerators = true;
    }

    private void RichEditBox_LostFocus(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IgnoreKeyboardAccelerators = false;
    }
}


That's really cool. Doesn't work with Uno4 unfortunately. The Xaml translator barfs on the Invoked.

I tried on an Uno project and got this warning Uno001 Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs.Handled is not implemented in Uno. This member or type is not implemented and will fail when invoked. but still compiles and works as expected. Does it work on your side too?

Which version of Uno were you using?

It should be v5.x. Are you getting an error instead of a warning in v4.x?

Yes, an error. We are working toward changing to v5 if for no other reason than no one wants to support v4.
